# DECLARE syntax in MySQLi Query | When To DECLARE variables in Query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**Apologies if posted already.**

Searched a lot on google but I'm not understanding how to use DECLARE syntax in MySQL Query.
I'm not expert in MySQL. I'm seeing these codes on internet for DECLARE syntax. Not seen complete query anywhere.

```
DECLARE @destlist varchar(max)
SET @destlist = SELECT destinations         FROM tbl_rings_to_groups WHERE id =   '1' AND user_id = '1'

SELECT count( id ) AS    totalDestination, group_concat(   ring_to_number ) AS phoneNumbers
 FROM tbl_destinations
 WHERE id IN (CONCAT('SELECT ',     REPLACE(@destlist), ',', ' UNION ALL     SELECT '))
```

**I'm using this for fetch results.**

```
   $result = $db->query("select from
    table where something = 
   somethingElse order by something");
```

Now, how to use `DECLARE` in above code.

**I'm trying this.**

```
  $result = $db->query(" DECLARE   @destlist varchar(max)
  SET @destlist = SELECT destinations    FROM tbl_rings_to_groups WHERE id =  '1' AND user_id = '1'

   SELECT count( id ) AS   totalDestination, group_concat( ring_to_number ) AS phoneNumbers
    FROM tbl_destinations
    WHERE id IN (CONCAT('SELECT ',      REPLACE(@destlist), ',', ' UNION ALL SELECT '))");
```

Is this correct way to using MySQL `DECLARE`?

Comment: `DECLARE` is a query, `set` is a query. You have three queries here. You need to seperate with semi-colons and use the `multi-query` function.

Comment: How to separate that. I'm not understanding it. Please help

Comment: `DECLARE   @destlist varchar(max); SET @destlist = SELECT destinations    FROM tbl_rings_to_groups WHERE id =  '1' AND user_id = '1'; SELECT count( id ) AS   totalDestination, group_concat( ring_to_number ) AS phoneNumbers
    FROM tbl_destinations
    WHERE id IN (CONCAT('SELECT ',      REPLACE(@destlist), ',', ' UNION ALL SELECT '));` ...assuming that query works already... then http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php